# how to delete specific user remotely

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to delete specific user example "UserExample" from around 400 windows PCs remotely so I made this batch file but this will delete local PC user not the remote any one can help me to improve that batch

note there is no domain server linked to these pcs

thanks

```
@echo On
Title %1 - DeleteUser from

:NETUSE
Net use  "\\%1\c$" 123456 /user:admin
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto :NETUSE

net user UserExample /delete

pause
EXIT
```

Comment: so if you do not have a domain it will delete local user, or do you have a workgroup?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard no all I want to do is to delete specific user remotely

Comment: maybe have a look at `WMIC /node:ComputerName process call create`. Simply run `wmic /?` from cmdline for help on the options.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you could use `WMIC` to connect to all the units listed in a text file and delete the user from them.

Something along the lines of this, perhaps:

```bat
WMIC /Output:UserDelete.log /Node:@PCList.txt /User:Administrator /Password:Pa55w0rd UserAccount Where "Name='UserExample' And LocalAccount='TRUE'" Delete
```

*I do find it hard to believe that a single user has created accounts on 400 PC's though*